# Python: How to extract specific parts of a string into a list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have string in Python from which I want to extract some information. It almost has the format of a list as you can see.

Is there an easy way to convert this into a list? As you can tell I am new to Python and regular expressions

I am after the data in "values" (3 arrays)
and the corresponding labels

[image: Output]

Comment: pls , post your code !

Comment: We cannot answer your question accurately unless it meets the question guidelines.

Comment: Parsing a screenshot is more fun!

Comment: Can't really do more than point you at [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) until you provide more context/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is javascript, so best try with json decoding.
When this is the only text you want to decode or you always have only once the text `"values":` 
, you can use

```
import json
mark = '"values":'
lists = json.JSONDecoder().raw_decode(text, text.index(mark)+len(mark))[0]
```

Comment: This works. Thanks so much. And apologies to the other posters for posting a screenshot. I couldnt get this to post as code.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
ast.literal_eval(re.search("data:(.*)",text_content).groups()[0])
```

Comment: you cannot use `literal_eval` with a `SRE_Match` instance